# Expandable Grid is not aligning with the parent grid

Tags: angularjs, ui-grid

I have a Expandable grid where the child grid uses the same headers/columns as the parent grid. when I expand the grid, the child grid is not aligning with the parent grid.

Any suggestions is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I got each column width of the parent grid as it is already rendered on the page. At the time of expanding the row, I have assigned the column width of the child grid with the parent column width. It worked successfully.

row.grid.getColumn('column1').drawnWidth: column1 is the name attribute of the column in parent grid.

```
   $scope.gridApi.expandable.on.rowExpandedStateChanged($scope,function(row){
                if(row.isExpanded){
                    row.expandedRowHeight = (row.entity.subGridOptions.data.length * 30);
                    row.entity.subGridOptions.columnDefs[0].width = row.grid.getColumn('column1').drawnWidth-1;
                    row.entity.subGridOptions.columnDefs[1].width = row.grid.getColumn('column2').drawnWidth;
                    row.entity.subGridOptions.columnDefs[2].width = row.grid.getColumn('column3').drawnWidth;
                    row.entity.subGridOptions.columnDefs[3].width = row.grid.getColumn('column4').drawnWidth;
                    row.entity.subGridOptions.columnDefs[4].width = row.grid.getColumn('column5').drawnWidth;
                    row.entity.subGridOptions.columnDefs[5].width = row.grid.getColumn('column6').drawnWidth;
                    row.entity.subGridOptions.columnDefs[6].width = row.grid.getColumn('column7').drawnWidth;
                    row.entity.subGridOptions.columnDefs[7].width = row.grid.getColumn('column8').drawnWidth;
                    row.entity.subGridOptions.columnDefs[8].width = row.grid.getColumn('column9').drawnWidth;
                    row.entity.subGridOptions.columnDefs[9].width = row.grid.getColumn('column9').drawnWidth;
                    row.entity.subGridOptions.columnDefs[10].width = row.grid.getColumn('column10').drawnWidth;
                    row.entity.subGridOptions.columnDefs[11].width = row.grid.getColumn('column11').drawnWidth;
            }
```